# c++ Iterate through a list to call a certain function

Tags: c++, list, function, oop, pointers

E.g. a class Unit has three functions:

```
class Unit{
    void StandUp();
    void SitDown();
    void Die();
}
```

I have a list of pointers `list<Unit*> UnitList;`

When I want everyone to stand up:

```
void EveryoneStandUp(){
    for(list<Unit*> it = UnitList.begin(); it != UnitList.eng(); it++){
        (*it)->StandUp();
    }
}
```

Now if I want everyone to SitDown, I would copy the code above and change `StandUp()` to `SitDown()`. For every new function I write, if I want everyone to do it, I have to have another for-loop body in my code.

Is it possible to put this for-loop body in another function, which I can reuse whenever I want to call a certain function from all of the members in the UnitList?

I feel like this must have answers somewhere else, I tried googling but have little idea which keywords I should look for. Thanks for answers!

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/

Comment: Try using `std::for_each`.

Comment: And [`std::mem_fn`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may do:

```
void Everyone(void (Unit::*method)())
{
    for (std::list<Unit*>::iterator it = UnitList.begin(); it != UnitList.end(); it++){
        ((*it)->*method)();
    }
}
```

And call it

```
Everyone(&Unit::StandUp);
```

but in c++11, your example may be rewritten as:

```
for (auto* unit : UnitList) {
    unit->StandUp();
}
```

which seems clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

you can use c++ algorithms available, 
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/

Answer (score 1):

It can be solved by having a helper function, which does the actual looping and have the member function to be called as an argument.

Something like this:

```
void UnitHelperFunction(void (Unit::*func)())
{
    for (...)
    {
        ((*itr)->*func)();
    }
}

void EveryoneStandUp()
{
    UnitHelperFunction(&Unit::StandUp);
}
```